# Navigator.pop() - How to pass `context` to be read by the navigator -

Tags: flutter, widget, navigator, stateless, stateful

I'm following a flutter tutorial ,,

and in this widget , to make it disappear after entering data I'll call the navigator class ,,
but in the tutorial I'll have to convert the stateless to stateful widget , althought I don't need it .

Haw can I use : `Navigator.of(context).pop();` with my stateless widget without getting error that context isn't defined ?
- How to pass `context` to be read by the navigator

CODE :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  final Function addNEW;
  NewTransaction(this.addNEW);

  void submitData() {

if (titleController.text.isEmpty || double.parse(amountController.text) <= 0 ){

  return;
}
    Navigator.of().pop();

    addNEW(
      titleController.text,
      double.parse(amountController.text),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              controller: titleController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
              controller: amountController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Add Transaction'),
              onPressed: submitData,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a stateless widget, you can't access `Context` outside of the build method. 
To solve the error, you can do one of the following:
1) Convert your `Stateless widget` to a `Stateful widget`

**OR**

2) Pass the context as a parameter to your `submitdata` function. Like the code below:

```
  void submitData(BuildContext context) {

if (titleController.text.isEmpty || double.parse(amountController.text) <= 0 ){

  return;
}
    Navigator.of().pop();

    addNEW(
      titleController.text,
      double.parse(amountController.text),
    );
  }
```

So when using it in the `FlatButton`, it would be something like below:

```
onPressed: submitdata(context),
```

3) Put the body of your `submitdata` function directly in the `onPressed` of you button.

Like the code below:

```
onPressed: (){
if (titleController.text.isEmpty || double.parse(amountController.text) <= 0 ){

  return;
}
    Navigator.of().pop();

    addNEW(
      titleController.text,
      double.parse(amountController.text),
    );
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: One can also pass the context as a parameter ```void submitData(BuildContext context)``` an then ```onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(context)```